# Algoritmo para combinação de certa letra

Tags: python, algoritmo

Tenho o seguinte problema, quero saber as combinações de certa letra na string, exemplo:

```
AAbA
```

Viraria

```
AAbA, AAb, Ab, bA, b
```

Cheguei no seguinte código, mas não contempla a resposta, ele cria combinações que não deveriam estar na resposta

```
def add_all_possibilities(item, nonTerminalWithEpisolon, production):
        numberNonTerminal = item.count(nonTerminalWithEpisolon)
        for i in range(numberNonTerminal + 1):
            new_production = item.replace(nonTerminalWithEpisolon, "", i)
            self._productions[production].add(new_production)
            self._productions[production].add(new_production[::-1])
```

Onde item é  a string "AAbA", nonTerminalWithEpisolon é "A" que deve ser a combinação dessa letra e production não importa para essa parte do problema

Comment: Vinicius poderia explicar o objetivo e como você chegou nas combinações desejadas?

Comment: É um algoritmo para Linguagens Formais, remoção de Episolon, a ideia é seguinte: o A pode ser considerado como um símbolo vazio ou não, então você tem que criar todas as combinações possíveis disso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A função `combinations`, do módulo padrão `itertools`, te dá todas as combinações possíveis pra uma determinada sequência e tamanho de janela:

```
import itertools
...
In [6]: list(itertools.combinations('AAbA', 4))
Out[6]: [('A', 'A', 'b', 'A')]

In [7]: list(itertools.combinations('AAbA', 3))
Out[7]: [('A', 'A', 'b'), ('A', 'A', 'A'), ('A', 'b', 'A'), ('A', 'b', 'A')]

In [8]: list(itertools.combinations('AAbA', 2))
Out[8]: [('A', 'A'), ('A', 'b'), ('A', 'A'), ('A', 'b'), ('A', 'A'), ('b', 'A')]
```

Podemos iterar sobre uma string em diferentes tamanhos de janela, lembrando cada combinação única:

```
import itertools

def pegar_combinacoes(s):
    combinacoes_unicas = set()
    # Pra diferentes tamanhos de janela...
    for i in range(1, len(s) + 1):
        # Pra cada combinação da string com esse tamanho de janela...
        for combinacao in itertools.combinations(s, i):
            # Não incluir combinações que são só 'A'
            if not all(ch == 'A' for ch in combinacao):
                # Adicionar a combinação às únicas vistas como string
                combinacoes_unicas.add(''.join(combinacao))
    return combinacoes_unicas

print(pegar_combinacoes('AAbA'))  # {'AbA', 'AAb', 'bA', 'AAbA', 'b', 'Ab'}
```

Esse método também funciona mais genericamente:

```
print(pegar_combinacoes('AAbAc'))
# {'AbAc', 'Ac', 'Ab', 'bAc', 'AAb', 'AAbA', 'AAbc', 'b', 'bc', 'AAAc', 'bA', 'AbA', 'AAc', 'c', 'Abc', 'AAbAc'}
```

Comment: Funciona mesmo, eu tinha chegado a usar o combinations do itertools, mas tava gerando combinações a mais também, valeu!

Comment: @ViniciusMacelai não estavas usando o `permutations`? Ele é mais "liberal" e também gera reordenações; geraria, por exemplo, `AbAA` ou `bAAA` que não são válidos nesse caso.

Comment: Eu vi esse também, mas era o combinations mesmo, acho que a diferença é que o parametro do combinations eu passei começando de 0 e não tive a sacada de retirar as combinações que são a mesma letra.